# Python module not found while executing python from bash in server side

Tags: python-3.x, bash, spring-boot

I want to develop a web framework. When I submit a request through REST API I need to execute a bash script. Inside the bash script, I basically run a python file:

```
/path/to/python /Users/<username>/path/to/file/a_python.py
```

In python script, I have some dependencies module for example 'numpy'. The current server is localhost and I am sure that the 'numpy' module is installed. Even if I execute the bash file from the command line it works as it is expected.

Due to some reason, I used "spring boot" as a backend other than the python framework. Is it possible to do it?

Any help in this regard highly appreciated :)

Comment: By "current server", do you mean the server where you are making the request or the server that runs the API?

Comment: both are localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in a following way:

1. create a virtualenv for this project using 'pipenv'
2. install all the dependencies there
3. write all the python code inside the project including the bash file
4. Call the rest api 
   & it works :)

so the required commands are:

```
1. mkdir projectdir && cd projectdir
2. pipenv --three
3. pipenv install numpy
4. mkdir moddir && cd moddir
5. vi index.py
6. cd ..
7. source $(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate
8. vi runfile.sh
```

using Spring boot run the runfile.sh and it gives the expected output :)